# phpactiverecord cant create object -undefined property

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm testing PHP Active Record but I'm facing some problems.

Setup AR

```
    ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg)
    {
        $cfg->set_model_directory( __DIR__ . '/models');
        $cfg->set_connections(array(
            'development' => 'sqlite://:memory:' ));
    });
```

models/Author.php

```
class Author extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $table_name = 'author';
}
```

models/Book.php

```
<?php

class Book extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $table_name = 'book';

        static $belongs_to = array(
            array('author')
        );

}
```

create new author

```
$author = new Author();
$author->first_name = 'John';
$author->save();
```

create new book

```
$book = new Book();
$book->title = 'Dead men tell no tales.';
$book->save();
```

create author table

```
CREATE TABLE [author]
        (
            [id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            [first_name] VARCHAR(128)  NOT NULL
        )
```

create book table

```
CREATE TABLE [book]
        (
            [id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            [title] VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
            [author_id] INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author(id)
        )
```

Creating an author object seems fine, creating a book raises an exception

```
 Uncaught ActiveRecord\UndefinedPropertyException: Undefined property: Book->author_id
```

Querying the database with standard PDO seems to work fine... so I was wondering if I miss something in Php Active Record

Answer (score 0):

`author_id` is a non-null foreign key so it must always be specified at insert time:

```
$book = new Book();
$book->title = 'Dead men tell no tales.';
$book->author_id = 1; // replace this value with an appropriate one.
$book->save();
```